# How to select multiple values from one table in text / list box and store in other table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, emp (pin, name, designation) and job (pin, date, type, group). If type is group in job table, I want the user to select multiple names from emp table. How this can be done in PHP?

Comment: What do you mean by "type is group"?

Comment: Consider to show some sample data to illustrate your question

Answer (score 0):

the sql ="select  * from emp,job where emp.pin=job.pin and job.group='' ";

I don't know you need this...

Please give the correct thing you want